# How to split a string from a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

My homework is as follows:

Step Two - Create a file called connections.txt with a format like:

```
Kelp-SeaUrchins
Kelp-SmallFishes
```

Read these names in from a file and split each string into two (org1,org2).  Test your work just through printing for now.  For example:

```
  cout <<  “pair  =  “ << org1 <<  “ , “ << org2 << endl;
```

I am not sure how to split the string, that is stored in a vector, using the hyphen as the token to split it. I was instructed to either create my own function, something like int ind(vector(string)orgs, string animal) { return index of animal in orgs.} or use the find function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach...

Open the file:

```
ifstream file{ "connections.txt", ios_base::in };
if (!file) throw std::exception("failed to open file");
```

Read all the lines:

```
vector<string> lines;
for (string line; file >> line;)
    lines.push_back(line);
```

You can use the regex library from C++11:

```
regex pat{ R"(([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+))" };
for (auto& line : lines) {
    smatch matches;
    if (regex_match(line, matches, pat))
        cout << "pair = " << matches[1] << ", " << matches[2] << endl;
}
```

You will have to come up with the pattern according to your needs.
Here it will try to match for "at least one alphanumeric" then a `-` then "at least one alphanumeric".
matches[0] will contain the whole matched string.
matches[1] will contain first alphanumeric part, i.e. your org1
matches[2] will contain second alphanumeric part, i.e. your org2
(You can take them in variables `org1` and `org2` if you want.)

---

If org1 and org2 don't contain any white spaces, then you can use another trick.

In every line, you can replace `-` with a blank.(std::replace).
Then simply use stringstreams to get your tokens.

---

Side note: This is just to help you. You should do your homework on your own.